# How to pass user meta_key and meta_value (values as array)

Tags: meta-query, user-meta, users

I want to pass user meta_key to meta_value, but the meta_value array is like this:

```
$user_biodata = array(
    'register_facebook_id' => 1311064406686333,
);
```

I want check if user is already registered through this function;

```
$wp_users = get_users(array(
    'number'       => 1,
    'count_total'  => false,
    'fields'       => 'id',

    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'user_biodata',
            'meta_value' => array( 'register_facebook_id' => 1311064406686333 ),
        )
    ),
));
```

But the result is always 1 even when the value not exist, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is not a valid way of retrieving and checking serialize data from the WP. You may insert array as a user meta but this array behind the scenes is transformed to serialize string something the MySql can handle.

There are options for searching with the LIKE operator but I don't endorse this use as it can lead to unexpected results.

```
$args = array(
'number'       => 1,
'count_total'  => false,
'fields'       => 'ID',

'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'user_biodata',
            'value' => 'yourValue',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),

    ),
);

$users = get_users($args);
```

Comment: Thanks, but not using '%%'.,

Comment: Yes @Opsional you are correct this is redundant.